# Metamask Swap rate

Tags: blockchain, metamask, binance-smart-chain, bsc, binance-chain

Hey can someone explain [this transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x26d5d6318c91303856d0e291e01bf27af3cd0f070dc71184877e0c611067ec55) to me? I tried to swap 117 USDT for [Altias](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/alitas/) but received just like 0,03 ALT ... Which is almost the same as when swapping 1 USDT on [this transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc8cacd149ae77eb9a960b9186b4d80a58d70911532daf8503873721f730ebe8d)

Comment: Can you explain in detail? This just looks like you bought Altias at a higher rate because the exchange rates changed in the two minutes that passed between the first block and the second block was added to BSC.

Comment: I just experimented with it... trying to trade

Comment: I just tried to swap 0,001 bnb for alt and 10 bnb for alt - in first case rate was 1
BNB = 42.438299 ALT while in the second it was 1 BNB = 0.017552778 ALT this is reproducable all the time - basically rate for tiny amount is fair while for bigger amount its rediculous.